# C++ win api ошибка

Tags: c++, winapi

При компиляции появляется такая ошибка

```
   undefined reference to `WindProc(HWND__*, unsigned int, unsigned int, long)@16'

LRESULT  CALLBACK WindProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); (**)
    wndclassex.lpfnWndProc = WindProc; (*)
```

Причина ошибки в строке (*), как понял функция (**) обрабатывает многочисленные сообщения. В моей программе задание одно, создать и запустить окно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка в коде Wnd32](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576228/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-wnd32)

Answer (score 1):

Код `LRESULT  CALLBACK WindProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);` только объявляет функцию, но не реализовывает ее. На что и ругается компилер. Напишите

```
LRESULT  CALLBACK WindProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uint, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
return 0;
}
```

в качестве заглушки.

Comment: Спасибо, я как понял ее надо объявлять перед WinMain ?

Comment: Не обязательно, но, думаю, так будет проще.