# Ошибка в коде Wnd32

Tags: c++, winapi

Программа выдает следующую ошибку:

> ```
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
> long __stdcall WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function _wWinMain@16   Win32_1 ...
> ```

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
TCHAR WinName[] = _T("MainFrame");

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE This,
    HINSTANCE Prev,
    LPTSTR cmd,
    int mode)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.hInstance = This;
    wc.lpszClassName = WinName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) return 0;


    hWnd = CreateWindowW(WinName,
        _T("Windowsddd"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        This,
        nullptr);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, mode);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        //TranslateMessge(&msg);
        //DispatchMessge(&msg);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас эта функция, `WndProc`, объявлена в начале модуля

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

но нигде не определена. Поэтому выдается сообщение линковщика, что он не может определить адрес этой функции в предложении

```
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
```

Вам следует определить эту функцию.

Эта функция может быть определена в простейшем виде, например, следующим образом

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{ 
    switch ( message ) 
    { 
    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break; 
    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 
        break; 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```